# exclude posts from a custom category

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have made a custom category "card_categories".
I want to exclude some posts from that category on the category page.
For eg :- category id 51 has posts with id's 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
Now I want that on the category page it should show posts only with post id 4,5,6,7,8,9

So, Is it possible that i can exclude posts from a category.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude posts from a particular category then you could try putting this in your functions.php

```
function exclude_posts_from_category( $query ) {
    $catname = "Put you category name here";
    if ( $query->is_category() && ( $catname == $query->query_vars['category_name'] ) ) {
        $query->query_vars['post__not_in '] = array( 1, 2, 3 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_posts_from_category' );
```

You can use `$query->query_vars['post__in '] = array( 1, 2, 3 );` in case you want to specify the posts that should be included ( It will only include the post id you mention and if they are in the current category ).